# how to choose a pdf from the gallery and open it into a pdf viewer?

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, file-upload, android-gallery

I am new in android developer.Image upload successfully on server(means convert image to encoded string and when retrieve encoded image convert to bitmap and display on image view).same I am trying PDF choose from gallery and display on PDF viewer but when I choose PDF from gallery i got bitmap null.
When click on btn(open gallery method call)

```
 SelectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // PDF selection code start from here .

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("application/pdf");

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PDF_REQ_CODE);

        }
    });
```

In onActivityResult Method

```
 if (requestCode == PDF_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        uri = data.getData();

        Log.e(TAG,"uri==>"+uri);
        **uri==>content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/812**

        SelectButton.setText("PDF is Selected");
    }
```

After click on upload button I got this url.

```
    public void PdfUploadFunction() {

    PdfNameHolder = PdfNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
```

**uri123==>/storage/emulated/0/Download/Search-By-Port.pdf**
}

so what should be do.I am trying user share every file(PDF,xlsx,doc) to other user......and how to display bitmap on image or PDF viewer..

above code I got url but which url pass to server.

Comment: A pdf is no image. So you cannot get a bitmap for it.

Comment: Do you want to upload pdf file to server ?

Comment: Use Intent.ACTION_VIEW for the obtained uri to let the user pick an installed pdf viewer.

Comment: `PDF choose from gallery`. No. The gallery knows nothing of pdf files. You use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Thats what you can say.

Comment: Check this link to pick a file http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html

Comment: uri = data.getData();
            Log.e(TAG,"uri==>"+uri);
            uri==>content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/812